# Is Arqade.SE a (relatively) good place to ask Linux gaming questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, questions

I noticed there is a Linux tag on Arqade.SE, as well as many Linux gaming-related tags. How would an experienced user rate this site for Linux gaming questions, including installation, graphics settings, and so forth? Would it rather be better to ask on Linux-specialised forums?

Here is an example of my own question: [Where is SuperTux user folder located on latest Debian Bullseye Stable install?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401673/where-is-supertux-user-folder-located-on-latest-debian-bullseye-stable-install) That question is specific to Debian Linux, and an answer that is suitable for Windows users, or even non-Debian Linux users, may not be suitable to that question specifically.

I'm seeing more and more people who choose Linux for gaming, oddly enough, so I wanted to know whether experienced users think that Arqade.SE is following that trend, and whether timely and quality answers, which are typical of SE network sites, are expectable for Linux users as well.

Comment: I guess this could be closed an opinion based, but from a personal perspective, I would say Linux is probably... second most popular of the "computer" gaming on this site.  But the gap is large between the most popular (Windows) computer gaming category.  I would say Mac is even lower in popularity.  That said, I don't see why you can't ask both here and somewhere else.  You could even self answer with a reference to another forum of where you asked should you receive an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your specific question, asking about a save or configuration file location on Linux is on-topic for Arqade. There are several existing examples of this:

> - [Where's the [Ace Attorney] save file stored in Linux / Ubuntu?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/400195/181240)
> - [Where is the Don't Starve save file located on Linux?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/106335/181240)
> - [Where are my [Pillars of Eternity] Saved Games kept, and can I back them up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/211228/181240)

As for Linux gaming in general, it's a topic that overlaps with multiple Stack Exchange communities. A question about Linux gaming could be on-topic for [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), or even all four* depending on the specific subject.

<sup>*Note that [cross-posting between multiple SE sites is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/351462)</sup>

One idea would be to post game-specific Linux questions on Arqade and more Linux-specific technical questions on another site. However, that isn't a solid rule you need to follow, especially when you factor in the existing technical questions on Arqade and the introduction of the linux-based Steam Deck.

In general, it will come down to your own judgement on which community is the best fit for your question.

For reference, here are examples of Linux gaming questions on SE sites:

> Arqade
>
> - [The Stanley Parable (the original game) hang up randomly after few minutes of playing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/400987/181240)
> - [Set a shutdown time for Steam Deck?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/400645/181240)
> - [Launching non-Flatpak Discord from Steam on a Steam Deck](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/400397/181240)
>
> Unix & Linux
>
> - [Is it possible to run Steam games using optirun?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/133921/223185)
> - [Remap surround speakers over HDMI Steam OS (Steam Deck)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/707386/223185)
> - [How to disable fullscreen mouse scrolling?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/520829/223185)
>
> Super User
>
> - [Is there any way of improving Doom graphics when running it on DOSBox?](https://superuser.com/q/1602236/358766)
> - [Can I play a video game on an ESXI server with a graphics card?](https://superuser.com/q/997171/358766)
> - [How do I add a non-Steam game from an SD Card in SteamOS?](https://superuser.com/q/1753032/358766)

Answer (score 3):

It's a sticky situation.

Usually, like our guideline about no mods questions, it's more that we can't really be a debug station for your very complex and very custom problem.

If your question is about 'What do I need to make X game work with Y common linux release' I think it would pass. Maybe borderline, but would pass.

But if it would be 'I'm with this highly custom Linux setup, and my Skyrim doesn't work with those 8 mods, what do I do' then that would not pass.

Comment: Our audience skews toward "general gaming", and the Linux gaming knowledge base is naturally a smaller subset of that. I wouldn't say OP's question is off-topic, but generally I would expect it to take longer to find an appropriate person to leave an answer.

Comment: Yeah it would definitely be like those questions on obscure games that stay unanswered for a while. But I do think the line is, at the end of the day, that we dont debug huge custom setups where about 60 variables could be the cause of the bug, and without recreating the setup there is no possible way we could help.

Comment: When you say "no mods questions" - do you mean the Minecraft close reason around mod crashes/abnormalities? If so, that should be clarified, because we do allow questions about mods typically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. As @TimmyJim suggests, "mods questions" is a bit ambiguous. Would you mind clarifying that, please? Thanks again.